# Django Model - Reference User ID

Tags: django, django-models

New to Django.

I'm creating a flashcard app where I have two models - Cards and Cards Set.

I want each card set in my database to be linked to the user who created them with a foreign key to the user id.

Having trouble understanding how to implement this.

Code so far

```
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL


class CardSet(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField() 
    description = models.TextField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, blank = True, null = True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

From what I understand, the first parameter of a Foreign Key in Django should be a model, but creating an instance Card Set in my database returns author_id as NULL. In this case, I want it to return the id of the user currently logged in.

Thoughts on how to solve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That has to be done in the view, or other code that creates the model instance.

Models are typically designed to be separate from request so they don't have a concept of "current" user.

Views on the other hand always have `request` as argument:

```py
def create_cardset(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CardsetCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.author = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect("somewhere")
    # fill the rest yourself
```

Same can be done in admin overriding one of save-related methods of ModelAdmin class.